# Auto-rewrite URL in php

Tags: php, function

I'm wondering if there is a pre-existing PHP function that will rewrite a given URL, adding a pre-defined application context. For example: I have a link like this:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

I would want this link to point to "/" under the production environment, but under the development environment it should point to "/app_context/". Is there any PHP function that can do this for me?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/base PS: it's a good practice to develop in a similar environment. Why not use `/` both in dev and prod environments?

Comment: Well guys, I appreciate the answers, but I was expecting something simpler. In Java, for instance, we have a JSTL tag called 'url' that makes this work for us. It is as simple as writing <c:url value="/" />. I'm looking for something like this.

Comment: have you checked link at my comment?

Comment: I've checked, but I forgot to answer, sorry. The problem remains with this tag, because I would have different values in "href" attribute under production and development environment. By the way, I realized that I could use a relative path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. I realized that I can just use relative path. For instance:

```
<a href="./index.html">Home</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always change the server config on your production server to match the live server by changing the document root for the production volume (unless you're on a shared host like Bluehost or something like that). There are exceptions to this... example:

`BluehostDomain1.com` root is `/`

If you host a second domain with bluehost, then it's a subdirectory (and accessible) of and from the first domain.

`BluehostDomain2.com` root is `/` by default and also accessible at `/BluehostDomain1.com/BluehostDomain2.com`.

In these cases I do something like this:

Make the code look for the domain executing it:

```
<?php
    switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']){
        case "production.server.com":
        $dR = '/';
        break;

        default:
        //Dev server dev.server.com
        $dR = '/app_context/';


    }


    $code = '<a href="$dR">Home</a>';
    $code .= '<a href="'.$dR.'about/">About</a>'; // /about/
    echo $code;
?>
```

Comment: This is pretty much same as my answer now that you've completely changed it from the regexp mess it was. Still -1 for hard coding the webroot.

Answer (score -1):

I usually define a WEBROOT constant that holds this value, and then prepend it to all links:

```
define('WEBROOT', str_replace('//', '/', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) . '/'));

<a href="<?php echo WEBROOT ?>">Home</a>
<a href="<?php echo WEBROOT ?>about/">About</a>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean?

Comment: They're using the code in both places. So they copy the code from one server to the other (or potentially show it in both urls simultaneously). For their uses, this method would only work if you're defining the webroot per recognized domain (either via an include or something specific to the domain), then applying the rewrite depending on which domain someone is on.

Comment: With this code, if the URL the file is accessed on is `http://localhost/foo/bar/` then `WEBROOT`'s value will be `/foo/bar/`, if it's accessed on `http://example.com/` `WEBROOT`'s value will be `/`. So yes, it will work regardless and it won't need an update if they change URLs (like your code would).

Comment: This code does assume, however, that all requests are run through the same file (`index.php` in root) (which is the case anyway with any decent framework).

Answer (score -2):

you can use something like:

```
<?php
if(/* test for developement environement */) {
    echo '<a href="/app_context/">Home</a>';
}
else {
    echo '<a href="/">Home</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: They would have to do this for every link.

Comment: how they distinguish between the production and development environments?

Comment: Production is `/`, Dev is `/app_context/`. So they want to be able to write one file and have it work in both I'm guessing.

Comment: the asker needs to give more information if he really want some help!!